# AlertDialog dispatchTouchEvent

Tags: java, android, view, android-alertdialog, touch-event

I want to transfer motionevent to dialog from view onTouchListener

I tried AlertDialog.dispatchTouchEvent but this doesnt work, event just stops at my view and dont go any further.

Code:

```
        final View v = new View(this);
        v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.packageName = getPackageName(); 
        getWindowManager().addView(v,params);
        v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    d.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setText(no);
                    d.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText(yes);
                } else {
                    int[] pos = new int[2];
                    Button b = d.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                    int w = b.getWidth();
                    int h = b.getHeight();
                    b.getLocationOnScreen(pos);
                    if(event.getRawX() < pos[0] + w && event.getRawX() > pos[0] && event.getRawY() < pos[1] + h && event.getRawY() > pos[1]) {
                        b.setText(yes);
                        d.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText(no);
                    } else {
                        b.setText(no);
                        d.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setText(yes);
                    }
                }
                return d.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
                //return false;
            }
        });
```

d - dialog that i want to transfer MotionEvent...
yes,no - Strings with text

Comment: I am making something like touch event proxy...the view is placing on top of the window...catches all the touch events and trasfers them to application...

Comment: Can you debug your `OnTouchListener` implementation?

Comment: @EugenMartynov yes i can debug...but what for?it seems to work properly...

Comment: So you are saying that even is passed to the dialog. Then the most possible issue is that coordinates of this even should be adjusted to be properly processed by the dialog.

Comment: Again, the event might be sent to the dialog, but (x,y) coordinates might/should be adjusted to be processed correctly. Assume 50,50 coordinate point is different point the dialog view because the top left corner of the dialog is not the same as your view.

Comment: @EugenMartynov yeah looks like this makes sense...but problem is...do you see in the code,that if the x and y of finger is under the button,it changes buttons text?this thing works how it should be))